# Signal R connection closing automatically

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Signal R event is going to close state automatically without even throwing any errors. How can i see why it got closed. No exception are throwning. The method which invoke signal R event is running inside a Task.Run()

Comment: You need to post some code snippets. Also, signalR is expected to close connections and reopen them in the background. Are you getting send failures ?

Comment: Not getting any errors, it directly going to close state. By any means we can check why it got closed?

Comment: Pls share your front-end code about creating the signalr client connection.